# Query for $type field in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a model persisted in Cosmos DB where I have some types that inherits from others types. Something like:

```
    class ParentType {
        public string name;
    }

    class ChieldTypeOne : ParentType {
        public string propertyA;
    }

    class ChieldTypeTwo : ParentType {
        public string propertyB;
    }

    class ThirdType {
        public List<ParentType> Parents;
    }
```

When I tried to query for all ThirdType documents where Parent.propertyB = 'somevalue', with Linq, I discovered that I can't use TypeOf<> with Cosmos DB .NET Client. I've try use SQL, but I don't know how to query for fields started with $ in the name to query for $type fields, that is created by Json.NET to differentiate for types of documents.

Some one has experienced this situation and found a solution?

Thks,

Luiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to use indexed access like:

`Select * From c Where c["$type"] = "TheType"`